# "Неотремонтированный" или "не отремонтированный"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

Сижу, работаю с большим массивом текста (редактура) и тут: "<...> занятия проводились в не отремонтированном здании <...>"
Все-таки "не отремонтированном" или "неотремонтированном", товарищи?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В **неотремонтированном** - слитно. Причастие, переходящее в данном примере в прилагательное, обозначающее качество: зависимого слова нет, противопоставления нет и не предполагается, НЕОТРЕМОНТИРОВАННОМ - отглагольное прилагательное, которое вполне можно заменить синонимом или близким по значению выражением.

Answer (score 3):

Если это документ, что-то техническое, спокойно рисуйте слитно.

Если художественный текст, то необходима консультация с автором, ибо

[*при раздельном написании логическое ударение падает на частицу **не**.*](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Мой любимый пункт у Розенталя:

> В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование и, как следствие,
>   двоякое написание; ср.: эта задача нетрудная (утверждается «легкость»)
>   – это задача не трудная (отрицается «трудность»); перед нами необычное
>   явление (т. е. редкое) – перед нами не обычное явление (мыслится
>   противопоставление: ...а исключительное, из ряда вон выходящее). При
>   раздельном написании логическое ударение падает на частицу **не**.

Comment: Это из монографии по истории. Полагаю, никаких особых акцентов там не предусматривалось по контексту, так что в соответствии с банальными правилами останавливаюсь на варианте со слитным написанием.

Answer (score 2):

Занятия проводились в неотремонтированном здании. Независимо от контекста, независимо от того, является ли это слово причастием (без зависимых слов, без противопоставления с союзом "а"), или же это причастие, перешедшее в  прилагательное, оно пишется слитно с НЕ-.

Comment: Это неверный ответ. Снизу Галина привела отрывок из "Справочника по правописанию и стилистике", из которого вытекает, что возможно и то написание, и другое.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Занятия проводились в неотремонтированном здании.**

**Это причастие, а не прилагательное (нет здесь качества, а есть значение действия),** но при отсутствии зависимых слов НЕ с причастиями пишется слитно.

Чтобы причастие (при наличии приставки, образованное от  глагола сов. вида) перешло в прилагательное, нужно чтобы имело место **переносное значение,** например: (1) **невыдержанный стиль** – не выдержанный в деталях стиль – стиль не выдержан (причастие); (2) **невыдержанный (вспыльчивый) человек** – невыдержанный в спорах человек – человек невыдержан (прилагательное).

Обратим внимание на то, что в полной форме при отсутствии зависимых слов и причастие, и отпричастное прилагательное пишутся с НЕ **слитно.**